# how to use addCredential() function while authenticating

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a custom user table for managing users.

```
User:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: user
  columns:
    user_login:
      type: string(50)
      notnull: true
      primary: true
    user_pass:
      type: string(100)
      notnull: true
```

after user click login with login form, username and password is checked against the database. If it is matched the user is set as authenticated with below line of code..

```
$this->getUser()->setAuthenticated(true);
```

Now how would I set the credential of the user using the following function? and is it necessary?

```
$this->getUser()->addCredential($WHAT ARE_THE_VALUES_THIS_ARRAY_SHOULD_CONTAINS);
```

what are the values should be in argument of the above method? Please explain more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you whether to use credentials or not. Credentials just unique strings cached in the session.

```
$this->getUser()->addCredentials(array('admin', 'user', 'chief', 'asd'));
// or
$this->getUser()->addCredentials('admin', 'user', 'chief', 'asd');
```

For mode examples look at the [tests](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/test/unit/user/sfBasicSecurityUserTest.php) and/or the [sfDoctrineGuardUser](https://github.com/Svel/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/blob/master/lib/user/sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php#L66-69) plugin.

You can use credentials to secure actions, but it's in the [docs](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/06-Inside-the-Controller-Layer#chapter_06_action_security).